# How to set the Linux terminal NOT to scroll down automatically when a running program outputs data to the terminal?

Tags: linux, command-line, unix, terminal, scrolling

Is it possible to set the terminal NOT to scroll down to the last line when the program that is currently running outputs data on the standard output ?

I have a program that is running and is constantly outputting data to stdout thus updating the terminal and the terminal automatically scrolls down to the last line and does not let me read the data that was outputted before or other commands that I have previously run.

Comment: Which terminal in particular are you using? xterm? urxvt? console/tty?

Comment: The *Scroll Lock* button might work as advertised depending on your terminal program.

Answer (score 8):

You can temporarily prevent scrolling by hitting CTRL-S on the keyboard, which will pause output until you hit CTRL-Q. This will let you read what's currently on the screen, but could also prevent the program from continuing depending on how it works.

I'm not aware of any actual setting for the shell itself that will prevent the screen from scrolling to the latest output, but you can achieve an equivalent result by piping output to less. 
Something like

```
    my_command | less
```

Comment: Pipe to less is the default answer, IMHO. +1  - for "see other commands I have run" - **h** in most shells, or **history**.

Comment: I have a problem. I forgot to mention that I am actually running linux on a virtual machine that is on a server proivded by my uni and I connected through Putty, I entered Ctrl+S and the terminal stopped responding.

Comment: That's normal, hitting CTRL-Q should resume it. If it does not, then it's possible you may need to change the terminal type of your putty configuration.

Comment: @barbecue but I want to be able to scroll up while the program tuns and does its job.

Comment: That's why I recommended piping to less. That will allow you to scroll up and down through the output. The CTRL-S option is just a way to temporarily freeze the screen so you can read what's on it without it scrolling by too fast.

Comment: What I do normally is `my_command | more` and scroll as needed.

Comment: @KrishnadasPC less provides all the functionality of more, but has additional features which make it more friendly. It's also available with most distros.

Comment: I do that with gcc error output g++ blabla |& less but I miss the color on colored text.

Answer (score 4):

Depends on the terminal program you are using.  You should be able to find this information in the documentation for it.  Most are based around the original `xterm`, which is the one I use, so I'll answer based on that.

For doing this interactively in an existing `xterm`, you can use the menu on the "Control middle mouse" button.  There is an item in the menu for "Scroll to bottom on TTY output" which is initially checked by default, you just click that and it will remove the check mark and the `xterm` will no longer jump to the bottom whenever there's output.

If you want a specific xterm to start off that way, there is a command line option `-si` which will start it off unchecked.  If you want this to be the default for all `xterm`s, you can set the `scrollTtyOutput` resource (wherever you set your X resources, and you can use the Xresource structure to make it apply only to some `xterm`s).

I knew all of these options existed, and just used `man xterm` right now to get the details.  One of the great feature of UNIX (followed for the most part in Linux) is that all of the documentation is right there.  You just have to look at it.